# Change Table numbers

Tags: header-footer, numbering

I created the following table in Latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\captionof{table}{Overview of selected Stablecoins} \label{tab:title} \\ 

\begin{tabular}{lllrrr}
\hline
 Name & Ticker & Type & Platform & Launch & Marketcap.\\
 \hline
Tether & USDT & Tokenised funds & Ethereum & 2014 & \$62.223.789.214 \\ 
Paxos Standard & PAX & Tokenised funds & Ethereum & 2018 & \$921.556.613\\ 
Digix Gold & DGX & Collateralized (off-chain) & Ethereum & 2018 & $4.207.210\\ 
PAX Gold & PAXG & Collateralized (off-chain) & Ethereum & 2019 & \$108.456.790\\ 
Dai & DAI & Collateralized (on-chain) & Ethereum & 2019 & \$5.500.483.542\\ 
Wrapped BTC & WBTC & Collateralized (on-chain) & Ethereum & 2019 & \$6.796.595.091 \\ 
Ampleforth & AMPL & Algorithmic & Ethereum & 2019 & \$125.480.264 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\\
```

This is supposed to be the first table in my Thesis. I want the name to be

> Table 1: Overview of selected stablecoins

However the Output is

> Table 4.1: Overview of selected stablecoins

(4 is the chapter and 4.1 is the subsection my table appears in)

How do I change that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Please also clarify whether the "4" in "4.1" pertains to a chapter-level, section-level, or subsection-level header.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you write `\captionof{table}{...}` instead of `\caption{...}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I make your code compilable (by adding `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, a missing `\` before a `$` sign and by adding `\usepackage{caption}`, then it works fine for me and produces a caption "Table 1: Overview of selected Stablecoins". That's why you should usually provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/237192).

```
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
   \centering
   \small
   \captionof{table}{Overview of selected Stablecoins} \label{tab:title}
   \begin{tabular}{lllrrr}
      \hline
      Name           & Ticker & Type                       & Platform & Launch &       Marketcap. \\ \hline
      Tether         & USDT   & Tokenised funds            & Ethereum &   2014 & \$62.223.789.214 \\
      Paxos Standard & PAX    & Tokenised funds            & Ethereum &   2018 &    \$921.556.613 \\
      Digix Gold     & DGX    & Collateralized (off-chain) & Ethereum &   2018 &      \$4.207.210 \\
      PAX Gold       & PAXG   & Collateralized (off-chain) & Ethereum &   2019 &    \$108.456.790 \\
      Dai            & DAI    & Collateralized (on-chain)  & Ethereum &   2019 &  \$5.500.483.542 \\
      Wrapped BTC    & WBTC   & Collateralized (on-chain)  & Ethereum &   2019 &  \$6.796.595.091 \\
      Ampleforth     & AMPL   & Algorithmic                & Ethereum &   2019 &    \$125.480.264 \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
This probably means that you have a `\counterwithin{table}{chapter}` in your code (probably in the preamble) or a package which does that for you. You should either find out where this comes from, or add a `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` at a suitable position, where the former one is the better idea.

I also took the liberty to improve your code a bit:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[group-separator={.}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
   \centering
   \small
   \caption{Overview of selected Stablecoins.} \label{tab:title}
   \begin{tabular}{lllllS[table-format=11.0]}
      \toprule
      Name           & Ticker & Type                       & Platform & Launch & {Marketcap. (\$)} \\ \midrule
      Tether         & USDT   & Tokenised funds            & Ethereum & 2014   & 62223789214       \\
      Paxos Standard & PAX    & Tokenised funds            & Ethereum & 2018   &   921556613       \\
      Digix Gold     & DGX    & Collateralized (off-chain) & Ethereum & 2018   &     4207210       \\
      PAX Gold       & PAXG   & Collateralized (off-chain) & Ethereum & 2019   &   108456790       \\
      Dai            & DAI    & Collateralized (on-chain)  & Ethereum & 2019   &  5500483542       \\
      Wrapped BTC    & WBTC   & Collateralized (on-chain)  & Ethereum & 2019   &  6796595091       \\
      Ampleforth     & AMPL   & Algorithmic                & Ethereum & 2019   &   125480264       \\ \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked for me, thank you!!